Multivariate LME
I am counting how often some patterns occur in many observations of timeseries data. I want to compare three conditions in two time intervals (so I average pattern counts over those intervals). There are multiple possible patterns and their counts are not independent (if a timepoint shows pattern 1 it can not also show pattern 2 in the same observation). In the end, my dataframe has subject_index (20subjects),condition (3levels), time_period (2levels), and for each of those the dependent variables count_pattern0, ... count_pattern4. I tried
from statsmodels.multivariate.manova import MANOVA
model_formula = 'count_pattern0 + count_pattern1 + count_pattern2 + count_pattern3+ count_pattern4 ~ condition * time_period + (1|subject_index)'
manova = MANOVA.from_formula(model_formula, data=data)

but everything (intercept, condition, time_period, condition x time_period and subject_index) comes out as significant and I am not convinced this is correct. I would prefer to treat condition and time_period as fixed and subject_index as random effects. Would a multivariate LME be a sensible choice here?
Thank you for your time!
